Excel Macro for Reading CSV as text
Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=readFile, DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True  when using this code for reading csv but date did not change as text . so how to solve  that ?  The problem is changing from '9月12日' to '2024/09/12'.
I just want '9月12日'
I want to read csv as text as the way it is, not to change date format .

Add FieldInfo:=Array(Array(n, xlTextFormat)) replacing n with the relevant column index. Docs: Workbooks.OpenText method, XlColumnDataType enumeration.

Please, try adding FieldInfo for all file columns in the next way:
Sub openCSVAsTextAllCols()
 Dim ReadFile As String:  ReadFile = "your file full name" ' use here the real CSV file full name
 
 Dim arrCSV, ColsNo As Long, arrField(), i As Long
 arrCSV = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(ReadFile, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
 
 ColsNo = UBound(Split(arrCSV(0), ","))  'the number of file columns
 ReDim arrField(ColsNo)
 
 For i = 0 To UBound(arrField)
   arrField(i) = Array(1, 2) 'build the array to open all columns as text
 Next
 
 Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=ReadFile, DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True, FieldInfo:=arrField()
End Sub

The above code will open the csv file with all columns as text. Handling such files, I suppose that your system is able to read/write such characters...
If you have problems from this point of view, try also using the next parameter: origin:=65001 (for files without BOM)...
